# error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<_Tp>::atomic() [with _Tp = node]’

Tags: c++, atomic, compare-and-swap

Having compile issue when using atomic with class based.

error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<_Tp>::atomic() [with _Tp = node]’
     stack() {
             ^

/usr/include/c++/5/atomic:185:7: note: ‘std::atomic<_Tp>::atomic() noexcept [with _Tp = node]’ is implicitly deleted because its exception-specification does not match the implicit exception-specification ‘’
       atomic() noexcept = default;
       ^

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>

class node
{
private:
    int data;
    bool hasTransaction;
public:    
    node(int& data) : data(data), hasTransaction(true) {}
    node() : data(10), hasTransaction(true) {}
};

class stack {
    std::atomic<node> head;
public:
    void push(int data) {
        node new_node(data);

        node current = head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

        while (!head.compare_exchange_strong(
                    current,
                    new_node,
                    std::memory_order_release,
                    std::memory_order_relaxed))
            ;
    }

    stack() {
        node a;
        std::atomic_init(&head, a);
        head.store(a);
    };
};

int main()
{
    stack s;
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    s.push(3);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `node` type's default constructor is not marked `noexcept`. The `std::atomic<T>` default constructor is marked as noexcept, so `T`'s default constructor must also be.

It should read:

```cpp
node() noexcept : data(10), hasTransaction(true) {}
```

However, you should probably know that unless your type is trivial, this "atomic" type will likely be made thread-safe via mutex. Thus, using atomics in this case is only making your life harder for no gain.

Typically you wouldn't want to use atomics unless it was for some primitive type (usually a raw pointer or an integer type).

Comment: which mean I should use atomic with type atomic<[int|float|....|type*]> ? Instead of using atomic<[class|struct]>?

Comment: @Oktaheta I'll put it this way: the more complex the type (and the larger the type), the less likely it is that it's actually using atomic operations at the hardware level. When atomic operations aren't used it needs to use e.g. a mutex to simulate it, which is much slower. Your `node` type only holds an int and a bool, so you could use `std::atomic<int>` and treat the high order bit as the `hasTransaction` flag via bitwise arithmetic. This would also drop the size of a "node" from 8 bytes to 4 bytes.

Comment: I see, this make clear to me, I would rather use raw pointer instead :)